# What GAS ERC20 tokens use?

Tags: ethereum, web3js, erc20

I would like to know what GAS the ERC20 tokens should use, like when I send OMG transaction, should I use OMG as the Gas or Ethereum as GAS?

I don't want to use ETH, so I am figuring out whether I can use the same token (i.e., OMG or other erc20 tokens) itself to sign the transaction.

Can you advise, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gas is a unit of work. Fees are paid in the form of `gas * gasprice`, and the result of that calculation must be paid from the ETH balance of the account that initiates the transaction.

There is no way to pay for tx fees in tokens.

Comment: thanks a lot Raghav! It helps a lot! Anyway the problem I face, for a project, I may need to create multiple addresses, which may accept eth or erc20 tokens. But the tranasctions(Trasnfer IN) to those multiple addresses are expected to be very small.  And some of the addresses even need not have ETH transferred in. So I can't easily transfer OUT the token, without adding gas to the account. While means, even more gas. Is there a way, in ethereum, I can have have all these multiple addresses tagged to a single private key, so that I can transfer with the gas stored from the common private key?

Comment: That is not possible. Your only other option would be to have a contract based wallet, and write code to sweep tokens in each wallet. You can then use a single regular ethereum address to initiate the sweeps.

Comment: Thanks Raghav, I didn't understand that idea much, though I feel like it might be a good thing to consider! Could you please kindly share me a bit more insight on it or share me some URLs to read further on this?  I am relatively new to ethereum!